# How to redirect users to specific sub-folder depending on user

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, redirect, directory

I'm working on a webpage that displays files in a folder. I got this webpage from open source website ["css-tricks"](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/display-styled-directory-contents/). I want to create a way that depending on the user that signs will get re-directed to a folder that is specified for them only. I was able to create a .htaccess that makes the user sign-in and a .htpasswd that has the login credentials.

For example,

There are 3 users (user1,user2,user3) and 3 folders with an index.php in each folder (folder1,folder2,folder3).

When "user1" signs in they get redirected to "folder1", 
if "user2" signs in they get redirected to "folder2" or "folder3" whatever I want them to be redirect too.

Would this be possible to do with the .htaccess file or like a php file?

**NOTE: PHP, .htaccess coding knowledge LIMITED! :(**

I hope someone could help me out or maybe point me in the right direction, if you need any extra information let me know! Thanks!

below is my index.php

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./.favicon.ico">
   <title>Invoices</title>

   <link rel="stylesheet" href="./.style.css">
   <script src="./.sorttable.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
 <h1>Directory Contents</h1>

 <table class="sortable">
     <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Filename</th>
   <th>Type</th>
   <th>Size</th>
   <th>Date Modified</th>
  </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody><?php

 // Adds pretty filesizes
 function pretty_filesize($file) {
  $size=filesize($file);
  if($size<1024){$size=$size." Bytes";}
  elseif(($size<1048576)&&($size>1023)){$size=round($size/1024, 1)." KB";}
  elseif(($size<1073741824)&&($size>1048575)){$size=round($size/1048576, 1)." MB";}
  else{$size=round($size/1073741824, 1)." GB";}
  return $size;
 }

  // Checks to see if veiwing hidden files is enabled
 if($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']=="hidden")
 {$hide="";
  $ahref="./";
  $atext="Hide";}
 else
 {$hide=".";
  $ahref="./?hidden";
  $atext="Show";}

  // Opens directory
  $myDirectory=opendir(".");

 // Gets each entry
 while($entryName=readdir($myDirectory)) {
    $dirArray[]=$entryName;
 }

 // Closes directory
 closedir($myDirectory);

 // Counts elements in array
 $indexCount=count($dirArray);

 // Sorts files
 sort($dirArray);

 // Loops through the array of files
 for($index=0; $index < $indexCount; $index++) {

 // Decides if hidden files should be displayed, based on query above.
     if(substr("$dirArray[$index]", 0, 1)!=$hide) {

 // Resets Variables
  $favicon="";
  $class="file";

 // Gets File Names
  $name=$dirArray[$index];
  $namehref=$dirArray[$index];

 // Gets Date Modified
  $modtime=date("M j Y g:i A", filemtime($dirArray[$index]));
  $timekey=date("YmdHis", filemtime($dirArray[$index]));


 // Separates directories, and performs operations on those directories
  if(is_dir($dirArray[$index]))
  {
    $extn="&lt;Directory&gt;";
    $size="&lt;Directory&gt;";
    $sizekey="0";
    $class="dir";

   // Gets favicon.ico, and displays it, only if it exists.
    if(file_exists("$namehref/favicon.ico"))
     {
      $favicon=" style='background-image:url($namehref/favicon.ico);'";
      $extn="&lt;Website&gt;";
     }

   // Cleans up . and .. directories
    if($name=="."){$name=". (Current Directory)"; $extn="&lt;System Dir&gt;"; $favicon=" style='background-image:url($namehref/.favicon.ico);'";}
    if($name==".."){$name=".. (Parent Directory)"; $extn="&lt;System Dir&gt;";}
  }

 // File-only operations
  else{
   // Gets file extension
   $extn=pathinfo($dirArray[$index], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

   // Prettifies file type
   switch ($extn){
    case "png": $extn="PNG Image"; break;
    case "jpg": $extn="JPEG Image"; break;
    case "jpeg": $extn="JPEG Image"; break;
    case "svg": $extn="SVG Image"; break;
    case "gif": $extn="GIF Image"; break;
    case "ico": $extn="Windows Icon"; break;

    case "txt": $extn="Text File"; break;
    case "log": $extn="Log File"; break;
    case "htm": $extn="HTML File"; break;
    case "html": $extn="HTML File"; break;
    case "xhtml": $extn="HTML File"; break;
    case "shtml": $extn="HTML File"; break;
    case "php": $extn="PHP Script"; break;
    case "js": $extn="Javascript File"; break;
    case "css": $extn="Stylesheet"; break;

    case "pdf": $extn="PDF Document"; break;
    case "xls": $extn="Spreadsheet"; break;
    case "xlsx": $extn="Spreadsheet"; break;
    case "doc": $extn="Microsoft Word Document"; break;
    case "docx": $extn="Microsoft Word Document"; break;

    case "zip": $extn="ZIP Archive"; break;
    case "htaccess": $extn="Apache Config File"; break;
    //case "exe": $extn="Windows Executable"; break;

    default: if($extn!=""){$extn=strtoupper($extn)." File";} else{$extn="Unknown";} break;
   }

   // Gets and cleans up file size
    $size=pretty_filesize($dirArray[$index]);
    $sizekey=filesize($dirArray[$index]);
  }

 // Output
  echo("
  <tr class='$class'>
   <td><a href='./$namehref'$favicon class='name'>$name</a></td>
   <td><a href='./$namehref'>$extn</a></td>
   <td sorttable_customkey='$sizekey'><a href='./$namehref'>$size</a></td>
   <td sorttable_customkey='$timekey'><a href='./$namehref'>$modtime</a></td>
  </tr>");
    }
 }
 ?>

     </tbody>
 </table>

 <!--<h2><?php //echo("<a href='$ahref'>$atext hidden files</a>"); ?></h2>-->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

below is my htaccess

```html
ErrorDocument 400 /.error.php
ErrorDocument 401 /.error.php
ErrorDocument 403 /.error.php
ErrorDocument 404 /.error.php
ErrorDocument 405 /.error.php
ErrorDocument 408 /.error.php
ErrorDocument 414 /.error.php
ErrorDocument 500 /.error.php
ErrorDocument 502 /.error.php
ErrorDocument 504 /.error.php
AuthType Basic
AuthName "My Protected Area"
AuthUserFile C:\\wamp64\\www\\Custom\\DisplayDirectoryContents/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
DirectoryIndex index.htm index.html index.shtml index.php default.php .index.php
```

below is my .htpasswd

```html
UserNanme:EncryptedPassword
```

and below is my .error.php

```html
<?php

$status=$_SERVER['REDIRECT_STATUS'];
$codes=array(
       400 => array('400 Bad Request', 'The request cannot be fulfilled due to bad syntax.'),
       401 => array('401 Login Error', 'It appears that the password and/or user-name you entered was incorrect. <a href="#" onclick="window.location.reload()">Click here</a> to return to the login page.'),
       403 => array('403 Forbidden', 'The server has refused to fulfill your request.'),
       404 => array('404 Not Found', 'Whoops, sorry, but the document you requested was not found on this server.'),
       405 => array('405 Method Not Allowed', 'The method specified in the Request-Line is not allowed for the specified resource.'),
       408 => array('408 Request Timeout', 'Your browser failed to send a request in the time allowed by the server.'),
       414 => array('414 URL To Long', 'The URL you entered is longer than the maximum length.'),
       500 => array('500 Internal Server Error', 'The request was unsuccessful due to an unexpected condition encountered by the server.'),
       502 => array('502 Bad Gateway', 'The server received an invalid response from the upstream server while trying to fulfill the request.'),
       504 => array('504 Gateway Timeout', 'The upstream server failed to send a request in the time allowed by the server.'),
);
 
$errortitle = $codes[$status][0];
$message = $codes[$status][1];

?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>That's an Error!</title>
 <style>
   html 
 {color:#333;
  font-family: "Lucida Console", Courier, monospace;
  font-size:14px;
  background:#eeeeee;}
 
 .content
 {margin:0 auto;
  width:1000px;
  margin-top:20px;
  padding:10px 0 10px 0;
  border:1px solid #EEE;
     background: none repeat scroll 0 0 white;
     box-shadow: 0 5px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
     position: relative;
}

 h1
  {font-size:18px;
   text-align:center;}

 h1.title 
  {color:red;}
 
 h2
  {font-size:16px;
   text-align:center;}
 
 p 
  {text-align:center;}

 hr
  {border:#fe4902 solid 1px;}

 </style>
</head>

<body>

 <div class="content">
 <h1>Sorry, but that's an error!</h1>
 <h1 class="title"><?php echo $errortitle; ?></h1>
 <hr>
 <p><?php echo $message;?></p>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Post your code, otherwise nobody can guess what you have...

Comment: i know but which code tho? my index.php? or htaccess? @NorbertBoros

Comment: Post everything you have so we can help...

Comment: Okay, I've added the codes. @NorbertBoros

Comment: Ok, first forget about doing it via .htacess. And second, are those "folders" pre-created for each user ? If so, you can easy redirect them, because basically a "folder" will become: example.co/folder/index.php. And third, you have nothing written for user logon, so if you want to keep your .htaccess method you will need to create the folders manually, and updated the htpasswd all the time..

Comment: how would i do the redirect? and i was planning on adding the folders manually and updating the htpasswd so that's okay with me. @NorbertBoros

Comment: You can do a permanent redirect using Redirect 301 / http://example.com/folder/ in your .htaccess but it's messy. Better to write some proper PHP authorization...

Comment: i search for php authorization and found this php manual: http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php but is it possible to do an if statment like if user1 is logged header( location:example.com/folder/subfolder)? @NorbertBoros

Comment: Yes it is possible, but you need to play a bit with it... I will post some code for you in a few minutes :)

Comment: I just saw your reply and was looking at the code I cant wait to test it out! I Really appreciate the help!!! :D @NorbertBoros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I made a quick mock with the code from the PHP manual for you. I also tested it and does exactly what you want.

Please make sure the "username" folder is created before hand, in my example I have: 'Norbert1','Norbert2','Norbert3' that means there must be a folder named 'Norbert1','Norbert2','Norbert3'.

```
<?php
ob_start();

$realm = 'Restricted area';

$users = [
        'Norbert1' => '123456', 
        'Norbert2' => '123456',
        'Norbert3' => '123456'
];


if (empty($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_DIGEST'])) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized');
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="'.$realm. '",qop="auth",nonce="'.uniqid().'",opaque="'.md5($realm).'"');
    die('This website requires authorization');
}


// analyze the PHP_AUTH_DIGEST variable
if (!($data = http_digest_parse($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_DIGEST'])) || !isset($users[$data['username']]))
{
    header('HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized');
    die('Invalid Credentials or no such user exists!');
}

    // generate the valid response
    $A1 = md5($data['username'] . ':' . $realm . ':' . $users[$data['username']]);
    $A2 = md5($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'].':'.$data['uri']);
    $valid_response = md5($A1.':'.$data['nonce'].':'.$data['nc'].':'.$data['cnonce'].':'.$data['qop'].':'.$A2);

    if ($data['response'] != $valid_response)
    {
        header('HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized');
        die('Invalid Credentials or no such user exists!');
    }
        // ok, valid username & password
        echo 'You are logged in as: ' . $data['username'] . PHP_EOL;

        header("Location: /". $data['username']."/");

        // function to parse the http auth header
        function http_digest_parse($txt)
        {
            // protect against missing data
            $needed_parts = array('nonce'=>1, 'nc'=>1, 'cnonce'=>1, 'qop'=>1, 'username'=>1, 'uri'=>1, 'response'=>1);
            $data = array();
            $keys = implode('|', array_keys($needed_parts));

            preg_match_all('@(' . $keys . ')=(?:([\'"])([^\2]+?)\2|([^\s,]+))@', $txt, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

            foreach ($matches as $m) {
                $data[$m[1]] = $m[3] ? $m[3] : $m[4];
                unset($needed_parts[$m[1]]);
            }

            return $needed_parts ? false : $data;
    }
?>
```

The rest is pretty self explanatory, good luck with your adventure!

Comment: It works perfect! does exactly what I need thank you so much!

Comment: I accidentally skipped to a folder with out having to login, so instead of doing example.com/indexpage/ i did exmple.com/indexpage/Norbert1/ and it worked thus letting me see all the pdfs on that page without having to login, and so how could I create an if statement or something to check if I or the user is signed in or not, for security reasons is why i'm asking, Thanks.

Comment: Well that is a different scenario... I currently don't have time but I will try to make another for you.

Comment: is there a way for me to get the user name of the user who is signed in?

Comment: Yes, $data['username'] contains it.